# return empty JSON by Flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a simple functions, which should returns JSON.

```
@app.route('/storage/experiments', methods=['GET'])
def get_experiments():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    experiments = db['experiments']
    cursor = experiments.find(request.get_json())
    print(dumps(cursor))
    resp = Response(response=dumps(cursor),
    status=200, \
    mimetype="application/json")
    return resp
```

print(dumps(cursor)) shows

`[{"current": "11", "date": "12.12.2001", "_id": {"$oid": "551c7b642349c517f5fa5223"}, "name": "xaxa", "voltage": "34"}]`

but returns empty brackets []

Comment: While creating your own Response object provides more flexibility, have you tried to simply return jsonify(dumps(cursor))?

Comment: yes, i tried jsonify(dumps(cursor)) return 500 error,
jsonify(list(cursor)) return {},
jsonify(cursor) return {}.
i don't have more variants

Comment: Just a quick guess, but is it working if you remove/comment out the print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is happneing because your database cursor (I don't know what database framework you use. `sqlalchemy`?) points at the end of your dataset when you want to return it, because your `print()`-statement was already iterating over it. It should work with this code when you just comment out the `print()` statement, because I can't see any other error in this code:

```
@app.route('/storage/experiments', methods=['GET'])
def get_experiments():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    experiments = db['experiments']
    cursor = experiments.find(request.get_json())
    #print(dumps(cursor))
    resp = Response(response=dumps(cursor),
    status=200, \
    mimetype="application/json")
    return resp
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jsonify function from the flask module.

**Edit**
Chrisitian is right I didn't notice that you were using a list. Anyways here's a decorator that I wrote exactly to solve this problem: [Json decorator](http://pastebin.com/BytgbCT9). Hope this helps.

Comment: `jsonify` only works for dictionaries, he is trying to serialize a list